# Yii CGridview with relational models

Tags: php, yii

I have searched for an answer on here but I haven't found one specific to my problem.

I believe I have set up the relations between my models incorrectly...
I have a CGridView that uses a model, one of these fields is a foreign id, I want to use that foreign id to grab a different field within the model. (e.g. Question model contains foreign key 'tag1', I want to use 'tag1' to find it's 'name' field in the table Tag).

View

```
    <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$questions->search(),
    'filter' => $questions,
    'columns' => array(
        array('class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn'),
        'text',
        'tag1',
        array('header' => 'Tag 1', 'value' => '$questions->tag1->text'),
        'na',
        'cca',
    ),
));
?>
```

Model

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tag1' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Tags', 'id'),
    );
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ??

Answer (score 0):

Try Giving this relation

```
 public function relations() {
        return array(
            'tags1'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tags', 'id'),    
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have the variable wrong, each row uses the dataprovider and gets stored in the variable `$data` so you just need to make it look like this:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$questions->search(),
    'filter' => $questions,
    'columns' => array(
        array('class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn'),
        'text',
        'tag1',
        array('header' => 'Tag 1', 'value' => '$data->tag1->text'),
        'tag1.text', //if you relation is setup correct you can also do this
        'na',
        'cca',
    ),
));
?>
```